# Database Creation Issues for Oracle 18c in Windows

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus, oracle18c

I'm trying to create a dummy database with a few example tables as part of a school project. I have no experience with Oracle, so please bear with me (if you have extensive knowledge on the topic, this read may be a good laugh).

Essentially, I have successfully installed Oracle 18c XE for Windows x64, and everything seems to be installed correctly. I just want to create a database and then a few tables inside of said database, but I'm running into a number of errors.

When following [Oracle's instructions](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/12c/r1/2day_dba/12cr1db_ch2install/12cr1db_ch2install.html#section2) for creating a database, I get the following error:
[image]

Somehow, I figured out that I need to make an instance of Oracle, so I did, and it's running according to services.msc. Here's the window of it's settings for reference:
[image]

Not sure of why I was getting such an error, I found another guide suggesting I open Oracle through the newly installed SQL Plus application. After running `/ as sysdba`, I am prompted to enter a User-Name and Password. Great. After finding [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/68939/error-ora-12560-when-trying-to-connect-windows-sqlplus-client-to-oracle-11g-lin), I managed to find my tnsnames.ora and listener.ora files, which look like this, respectively:

```
ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = CLRExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )
```

```
DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = XE

SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\app\Nolan\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
      (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:C:\app\Nolan\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE\bin\oraclr18.dll")
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = DESKTOP-495S61D)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
  )
```

Trying `system@"DESKTOP-495S61D:1521/orcl"` or `system@"DESKTOP-495S61D:1521/example"` as a username and entering anything for the password throws `ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor`.

Nothing I enter into SQL Plus is working for a username. Furthermore, every time I enter a username, it stops taking any input for a password. I cannot paste anything nor can I type. I don't understand what I've done wrong or why Oracle hates me so much. If anyone could shed some light on my situation and help me get back on track, I would be forever indebted.

Comment: Your first picture has a trace file; have you looked in there to find out more details about the error?

Comment: @MT0 I don't really understand what I'm looking for, but this line shows up a few times: ```[main] [ 2020-11-10 19:02:47.634 EST ] [nativesystem.WindowsNative.Native]  Key 'Software\Oracle\Ocr' does not exist```

Comment: You say you installed XE 18c but you link to the documentation for regular Oracle database creation. If you have in fact installed XE - eXpress Edition - then you already have a database and you don't need to create one. [Read the documentation here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/xeinw/installing-oracle-database-xe.html#GUID-8A8E5F6D-F00E-40BD-B74D-A41CCC502AE9). Unless you didn't install XE? Sorry if you find this confusing, but please remember Oracle is an enterprise grade product, which is not always friendly for beginners.

Comment: Thank you @APC I had been following that documentation but the problems persisted. I decided to uninstall Oracle and do a fresh reinstall, and that got it working.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to create a database. Your tnsnames.ora and listener.ora seem to be just configured for calls to external procs. You would have something with ORCL as the SID if you created a default database.

Bobby

Comment: Unfortunately when I try to make a database through the Database Configuration Assistant, I still get the NullPointerException message. Is there another way to create a database?

Comment: Did you look at the 18c XE installation guides? You may not have something you need like Java installed. https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/xeinw/installation-guide.html#GUID-C3C5B05A-3BEB-4373-96D0-80BBADFBD6A4

Comment: I ended up uninstalling/reinstalling and everything went smoothly the second time around. Thanks for the help!